# LINUX: How to AWK to find maximums in every unique line

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file with this record
myFile.txt :

```
firstname lastname note 
Ben Quick 12
Fred Free 10
Mark Marked 18
Mark Marked 20
Ben Quick 8
```

and want to print every unique person with his maximum note
the result will be like this

```
firstname lastname maxNote
Ben Quick 12
Fred Free 10
Mark Marked 20
```

so I have this awk script

```
#!/bin/awk -f


BEGIN {
    print "firstname lastname maxNote"
}

NR > 1 { 
    list[$1," ",$2]++
}

END {
    for(l in list)
        print l
}
```

it print only unique firstname + lastname
my question is : how can I sort them by note and print the whole line of each  ?

your help is appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{print; next}
     {
       note=$NF                            # save note from last field
       NF--                                # remove last field from $0
       name=$0
       if(a[name]<note){a[name]=note}
     }
     END{
       for(i in a){print i,a[i]}
     }' file
```

Output:

```
firstname lastname note 
Fred Free 10
Ben Quick 12
Mark Marked 20
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following. Written and tested with GNU `awk` should work with any `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
match($0,/[^0-9]*/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)
}
{
  arr[val]=(arr[val]>$NF?arr[val]:$NF)
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                     ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                                   ##Checking condition if this is first line.
  print                                   ##printing current line here.
  next                                    ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
match($0,/[^0-9]*/){                      ##using match function to match till any digit comes in line.
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)           ##Creating val which has sub string of current line, with values of RSTART and RLENGTH.
  sub(/[[:space:]]+$/,"",val)             ##Substituting spaces coming at last in val wit NULL here.
}
{
  arr[val]=(arr[val]>$NF?arr[val]:$NF)    ##Creating array with index of val and keeping only maximum value by comparing with last field os current line.
}
END{                                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){                        ##Traversing into arr elemennts now.
    print key,arr[key]                    ##Printing key and its value here.
  }
}
'  Input_file                             ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR==1     {print; next} 
                 {k=$1 FS $2} 
       max[k]<$3 {max[k]=$3} 
       END       {for(k in max) print k, max[k]}' file

firstname lastname note
Fred Free 10
Ben Quick 12
Mark Marked 20
```

another approach

```
$ sed 1q file; sed 1d file | sort -k1,2 -k3nr | awk '!a[$1,$2]++'

firstname lastname note
Ben Quick 12
Fred Free 10
Mark Marked 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk, sort, and cut in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '{print (NR>1), $0}' file | sort -k1,1n -k4,4rn | cut -d' ' -f2- | awk '!seen[$1,$2]++'
firstname lastname note
Mark Marked 20
Ben Quick 12
Fred Free 10
```

Comment: is there any way to add the `sort` and `cut` command in a awk script ?

Comment: Yes there are a couple of options but neither would be as efficient as using the pipeline I showed and it won't be able to handle as large input files and some of those options wouldn't be portable to all awks.

Comment: i run this but 'mark marked' gives me 18 instead of 20

Comment: Then you either copy/pasted the script incorrectly or the input you're running it against doesn't look like the input you posted. When you run the script I provided against the sample input you provided it **will** produce the expected output you provided as shown in my answer.

Comment: i recheck the file inputs and make sure to copy the code well,  but still

Comment: If you edit your question to show a copy/paste of your screen showing exactly the script you're running, exactly the input you're running it against, and exactly the output you get then I'll take a look to see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: oh I was adding the filename at the end of the last awk , but now it works